# Compare two arraylist contents and store unmatched contents in another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I want to compare two arraylist contents .

I am storing objects in them in this way.

for Arraylist 1:

```
Employee e1=new Employee();

e1.setID("1");
e1.setID("2");

ArrayList<Employee>list1 = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 

if(e1!=null){
    list1.add(e1);
}
```

for Arraylist 2:

```
Employee e2=new Employee();

e2.setID("1");
e2.setID("2");
e2.setID("4");

ArrayList<Employee>list2 = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 

if(e2!=null){
    list2.add(e2);
}
```

Now I am trying to compare the above arraylist contents in this way

```
ArrayList<Employee>unmatchedList = new ArrayList<Employee>();   

for (Employee l1 : list1){                               
    if(!list2.contains(l1.getID())){    
        System.out.println("list2 does not contains this ID"+l1.getID());   
        Employee e3=new Employee();          
        e3.setID(l1.getID());

        if(unmatchedList==null){            
        unmatchedList=new ArrayList<Employee>();            
        unmatchedList.add(e3);          
        }

        if(unmatchedList!=null){                            
            unmatchedList.add(e3);              
        }                       
    }
}
```

But I am not gettting correct unmatchedList contents as "4" only .
I am getting unmatchedList as "1" and "2" which is wrong.
So how can I get unmatched contents only in "unmatchedList"

Comment: You might want to use a `Set` instead of an `ArrayList`. Comparison is done easily there. Though a `Set` won't let you store duplicate values.

Comment: please provide code of Employee class.

Comment: @svz admittedly, a duplicate employee sounds a little freaky - or twins maybe? I mean my employer would love to duplicate us but he has never succeeded...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class `Employee` is defined like this :

```
public class Employee {

private int id;

public Employee(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Id : " + this.id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Employee) && this.id == ((Employee)obj).getId();
}
```

in the Main method, you can retrieve the unmatch contents like this :

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
   List<Employee> l1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   l1.add(new Employee(1));
   l1.add(new Employee(2));
   l1.add(new Employee(3));
   l1.add(new Employee(4));
   l1.add(new Employee(5));


   List<Employee> l2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   l2.add(new Employee(4));
   l2.add(new Employee(5));


   l1.removeAll(l2);
   System.out.println(l1);

}
```

This will print : `[Id : 1, Id : 2, Id : 3]`

Note that for this work you must override the `equals` method.

Comment: Note that this actually changes the content of l1. In the OP's question, the elements were stored in a third list. I gave a short sample of this in my answer, it's just another constructor call to copy the list.

Comment: your solution worked perfect for me.

but how should I override method if i want to achieve it for multiple variables.
example: currently we have only one variable private int id; but if i have other variables like private int id1, id2,id3 ; so how can i override equals methods for them?

Comment: You should override the method equals. equals is a method defined in Object that compares the content of of objects. The equals method provided is just and example. you must define your equals method so he can fit your needs.

Comment: yes i have override equals method for id1 in Employee class but how can I override equals method in Employee class for id2, id3 and so on.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you want to override equals, herer is an example http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code: -

```
if(!list2.contains(l1.getID())){
```

Your `list2` is an `ArrayList<Employee>`, and you are checking for containment of `l1.getId()`. So, your `if` condition will always be true.

---

You should rather override `equals` and `hashCode` method in your `Employee` class, and just use : -

```
if(!list2.contains(l1))
```

for checking whether list2 contains employee `l1`.

---

And why are you setting your `id` 3 times back to back before adding it to list. It will not add all the three id's, but only a single `Employee` with last value set for id. You need to correct it: -

```
e2.setID("1");
e2.setID("2");
e2.setID("4");

list.add(e2);  // Will only add one Employee with id = 4
```

Comment: so how should I need to check to get unmatched contents by comparing both list?

Comment: @PravinG.. Also note that, to get unmatched list, you need to do the check from both the list. First check whether elem of list1 is in list2, and then the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `equals` method to your employees that compares them by their ID, make a copy of `list2` and call `removeAll`:

```
List<Employee> list1 = ...;
List<Employee> list2 = ...;
List<Employee> unmatchedList = new ArrayList<Employee>(list2);
unmatchedList.removeAll(list1);
```

For a complete example, see @Dimitri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Set` for your scenario. May be this examples will help you.

The `Employee` class

```
package com.yourcomp;

/**
 * <br>
 * <div style="width:600px;text-align:justify;">
 *
 * TODO: Class comment.
 *
 * </div>
 * <br>
 *
 */
public class Employee {

    private int id;

    /**
     * Constructor for Employee. <tt></tt>
     */
    public Employee() {
        this(-1);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for Employee. <tt></tt>
     */
    public Employee(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the id.</tt>
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id.
     *
     * @param id <tt> the id to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.id == ((Employee)obj).id;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + "]";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Integer(id).hashCode();
    }



}
```

The `TestEmployee` class :

```
package com.yourcomp;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * <br>
 * <div style="width:600px;text-align:justify;">
 *
 * TODO: Class comment.
 *
 * </div>
 * <br>
 * 
 */
public class TestEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creating the first set with employees having ID's 1 to 5
        Set<Employee> set1 = new HashSet<Employee>();
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++) 
            set1.add(new Employee(i));

        System.out.println(set1); // printing it

        // creating the first set with employees having ID's 3 to 8.
        // note that now you have two employees with same ID, 3 & 4
        Set<Employee> set2 = new HashSet<Employee>();
        for(int i=3;i<8;i++)
            set2.add(new Employee(i));

        System.out.println(set2);// printing the second set

        // creates a final set to contain all elements from above two sets without duplicates
        Set<Employee> finalSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
        for(Employee employee:set1)
            finalSet.add(employee); // adds first set content


        for(Employee employee:set2)
            finalSet.add(employee); // adds second set content. If any duplicates found, it will be overwritten

        System.out.println(finalSet); // prints the final set



    }
}
```

and the ouput

```
[Employee [id=1], Employee [id=2], Employee [id=3], Employee [id=4]]
[Employee [id=3], Employee [id=4], Employee [id=5], Employee [id=6], Employee [id=7]]
[Employee [id=1], Employee [id=2], Employee [id=3], Employee [id=4], Employee [id=5], Employee [id=6], Employee [id=7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend a Set to do the difference, and if you can use Sets then I would use the difference-method of Guava-Sets:
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29